# How can i use Inlinekeyboard in webhook method telegram Bot ? c#

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I use c# and telegram.bot library.
When i use getUpdates method everything is ok but in webhook method not ok

in GetUpdates method when i write below code in `OnCallbackQuery` event  everything is ok and bot get answers

```
  private static void Bot_OnCallbackQuery(object sender,        
                 Telegram.Bot.Args.CallbackQueryEventArgs e) 
                    {
                     long b;
        if (e.CallbackQuery != null && long.TryParse(e.CallbackQuery.Data, out b))//show Post
        {
            //PostContent
            var post = dba.BlogPosts.Find(Convert.ToInt64(e.CallbackQuery.Data));
            if (post != null)
            {
                string removedTag = Regex.Replace(post.Content, "<br>", Environment.NewLine);
                removedTag = Regex.Replace(removedTag, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
               // HtmlTagsRemover.CleanTagsExceptPbr(postContent.Content);

                Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, removedTag, parseMode: ParseMode.Html);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.CallbackQuery != null && e.CallbackQuery.Data.Contains("more_")) // user clicked on MoreButton
            {

                Post p = new Post();
                var posts = p.BlogPostPaging(PostsList, 5, moreCount);
                #region InlineKeyboard

                var inlineButtons = posts.Select(title => new[]
                        {InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(title.Subject, title.BlogPostId.ToString())})
                    .ToArray();

                InlinePostsKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(inlineButtons);
                #endregion

                if (posts.Count>0)
                {
                    Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, "page: " + moreCount, replyMarkup: InlinePostsKeyboard);// ShowMoreButton
                    Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, "see More...", replyMarkup: InlineBtnMoreKeyboard);// MoreButton
                    moreCount++;

                }
                else
                {
                    Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id,
                        "End");
                }
    }
```

but when i want use above code in webhook method , bot does not work And no response is received from bot

```
#region QueryCallBack
            var e = update;

            long b;
            if (e.CallbackQuery != null && long.TryParse(e.CallbackQuery.Data, out b))//show post
            {
                await Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Id, "test1");

                //post Content
                var post = _blogPost.EfGetOneBlogPost(b);
                if (post != null)
                {
                    var removedTag = Regex.Replace(post.Content, "<br>", Environment.NewLine);
                    removedTag = Regex.Replace(removedTag, "<.*?>", string.Empty);

                    await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, removedTag, parseMode: ParseMode.Html);
                    return Ok();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (e.CallbackQuery != null && e.CallbackQuery.Data.Contains("more_")) // user clicked on MoreButton
                {

                    TelegramPostsPaging p = new TelegramPostsPaging();
                    var posts = p.BlogPostPaging(PostsList, 5, moreCount);
                    #region InlineKeyboard
                    var inlineButtons = posts.Select(title => new[]{InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(title.Subject, title.BlogPostId.ToString())}).ToArray();

                    InlinePostsKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(inlineButtons);
                    #endregion

                    if (posts.Count > 0)
                    {
                        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, "page: " + moreCount, replyMarkup: InlinePostsKeyboard);// show SeeMore Button
                        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id, "see More...", replyMarkup: InlineBtnMoreKeyboard);// show SeeMore Button
                        moreCount++;
                        return Ok();


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.CallbackQuery.Message.Chat.Id,
                             "End");
                        return Ok();

                    }


                }

            }
```

I don't know how to use CallBackQuery in webhook; but in update method i use in `OnCallbackQuery` event.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the update in the webhook? Because the built-in serializer of ASP.NET does not correctly parse the update, you should instead take it as a string and then deserialize it using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Do you have a project for sample?

Comment: It's simple, actually. You get Newtonsoft.Json on nuget and use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Update>(thestringyougot)

Comment: cannot convert from 'Telegram.Bot.Types.Update' to 'string' ,`var updateConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Update>(update);`